# How to disable Monitor Brightness keys (DELL N4010) in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, dell, brightness

I want to disable or remap the Monitor Brightness Keys for my DELL N4010 as it causes Ubuntu 12.04 to freeze on a black screen if I adjust brightness through those keys.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in my HP computer is making the Fn keys Fn keys by default, instead of the keys for brightnes, volume, etc. To use them now I have to use the blue <kbd>Fn</kbd> button.

To do this you have to enter your BIOS setup (by pressing a key such as <kbd>F1</kbd> or another F key, or <kbd>Esc</kbd>) at the very beginning of boot. Then go to system configuration optionsand change **Action Keys Mode** to **Disabled**.

Comment: thanks a lot Ramon, that BIOS thing works out for now. Changed from Multimedia first to Fn key first.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :)